# Grails Restful webservice using URL mappings

Tags: rest, grails

I am using Grails 3 version for building RESTFUL web services and followed the below steps to provide the API to validate user. Instead of json response getting the login url Of application, please let me know if I miss any steps

STEP 1. Created controler which extends RestfulController

class MyExampleController extends RestfulController {

```
static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
MyExampleController() {
    super()
}

UserService userService

static allowedMethods = [
        index        : ["POST", "GET"],
        history      : ["GET", "POST"],
        validateUser      : ["GET"]
]

def index() { }

def validateUser() {
    println "User........${params.uid}"
    String userName = params.uid
    Map info = userService.getUserInfo(userName)
    if (!info) {
        render status: org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        return
    }
    render info as JSON

}
```

}

Step 2 : In the URL Mappings.groovy file added below line

"/roomCheckAPI/login/$uid?"(controller: "myExample",action:"validateUser")

Using below curl request to see the json response, but getting the login url of the application

curl -v -g -k https://localhost:8444/appName/roomCheckAPI/login/user1

Response: Redirecting to login  URL of application instead of json response

Comment: "Response: Location: https://sso.djjdp.juvjus.state.nc.us:8443/cas-server/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8444%2FNCJOIN%2Flogin%2Fcas" - It looks like you are being redirected to the NC Department Of Juvenile Justice CAS Server for login.  Is there a plugin in your app that might be causing that?  Is there an interceptor in your app that might be causing that?  There is definitely something relevant outside of the `MyExampleController` code that you show.

Comment: Do you have a plugin in your app that is configured to redirect unauthenticated requests for this url to a login page?

Comment: Yes @j I do have CAS server plugin in the build.gradle file

Comment: "Yes @j I do have CAS server plugin in the build.gradle file" - Are you asking how to not have this endpoint be subject to your security plugin rules?

Comment: Yes @JeffScottBrown, When the client hits the webservice url it should not go through the CAS server login and instead need access to the webservice end points directly

Comment: Are you specifying your rules by way of `grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules`?

Comment: Configred the below changes in the application.groovy under grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [//Stateless chain for REST API
        [
                pattern: '/api/**',
                filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
        ],

        //Traditional chain for form based login
        [
             pattern: '/**',
                filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter']